# Rails 4 - Helper Method - use in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, helper

I'm trying to figure out how to use helper methods in Rails 4.

I have two models, organisation and preferences.

The associations are:

```
Organisation has_one :preference
Preference belongs_to :organisation
```

In my preference table, I have an attribute called :prior_notice_required

In my organisation view, I'm trying to display the organisation's preferences. In my organisation view folder, I have a partial called preferences.

In my OrganisationsHelper.rb, I've tried this:

```
module OrganisationsHelper

    def publicity_notice_required
        if @organisation.preference.prior_notice_required == true
            'Prior notice of publicity is required'
        else
            'Prior notice of publicity is not required'
        end
    end
```

In my organisation preferences partial, I then try each of these:

```
<%= @organisation.preference.prior_notice_required(publicity_notice_required) %>
<%= publicity_notice_required(@organisation.preference) %>

<%= publicity_notice_required(@organisation.preference.prior_notice_required) %>
```

I can't figure out how to get this working. Does anyone have any experience with helpers to see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what is happening right now with this code? are you getting an error? if so, what error? please provide as much info on exactly what's happening as you can

Comment: Try `<%= publicity_notice_required %>`. You've defined a method that takes no parameters and returns a String, so call/use it like that.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as calling `<%= publicity_notice_required %>` in the view.

Rails Helpers are modules which are included across your application. This makes life easy but also has some drawbacks when it comes to Encapsulation & a good separation on concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is right-  but it seems to be working.

I change my view to:

```
<%= publicity_notice_required(@organisation.preference) %>
```

and my helper to:

```
def publicity_notice_required(organisation)
        if @organisation.preference.prior_notice_required == true
            'Prior notice of publicity is required'
        else
            'Prior notice of publicity is not required'
        end
    end
```

I'm not sure why the (organisation) needs to be in brackets or if its actually meant to include the preference as well. Hope this helps someone.